# Does isolates in flutter queue the values received on its port ?If yes , then how can I ensure that it works only on latest message?

Tags: flutter, dart

I will be passing camera image stream in an isolate for processing and I want that after processing current frame ,the isolate start processing the latest frame received .

Comment: *"I will be passing [...]"* - so dont pass if your `Isolate` is busy

Comment: @pskink Well, I thought if there was an easy way that would have been nice , but now i have to implement  isolate for bi directional communication .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , isolate process requests in queue and in order to work on latest data just have some check in main isolate which waits for response from the spawned isolate .